# How do I add in jump marks (bookmarks) into a CMS page on Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, cms

I am trying to create an FAQ page for our website on Magento 1.9 and I want to list the questions at the top and then jump link them to the answers. I am using the CMS creator. Does anyone know how/if I can do this on a CMS page?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you are going to have all your content on a single page? In which case yes.

You need to use anchor links.

https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/link/html-anchor-link.html

Link:

`<a href="#example">Example headline</a>`

Will jump to:

`<h5><a id="example"></a>Example headline</h5>`